# Bigquery Can't Upload RECORD Data Type File

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to upload my Sales data into Bigquery. The file contains `STRUCT` (`RECORD`) data type, therefore, I have to upload my file as ndjson.

However, once I do that, I get the error message: '`Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.`"

The ndjson I'm trying to upload look something like this: `{"SalesOrder": "SalesOrder", "CreatedBy": "CreatedBy", "CustomerID": "CustomerID", "SalesChannel": "SalesChannel", "SalesChannelType": "SalesChannelType", "CreatedDate": "CreatedDate", "WebDiscount": "WebDiscount", "RevenueFromPlatform": "RevenueFromPlatform", "DeliveryFee": "DeliveryFee", "PriceBeforeVAT": "PriceBeforeVAT", "VAT": "VAT", "DeliveryChannel": "DeliveryChannel", "DeliveryStatus": "DeliveryStatus", "Payment.Status": "Payment.Status", "Payment.Channel": "Payment.Channel", "Payment.Value": "Payment.Value", "Payment.Date": "Payment.Date", "Product.SKU": "Product.SKU", "Product.UnitsSold": "Product.UnitsSold", "Product.UnitPrice": "Product.UnitPrice", "Product.Discount": "Product.Discount", "Product.Price": "Product.Price", "": ""}`

How do I solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide an example of the newline delimited JSON you are tying to import? As well as the DDL statement (CREATE TABLE) you are trying to load into. Additionally can you provide the parameters you are giving to the BQ LOAD command.

Comment: @Spasnof I have provided the example of the ndjson i'm trying to import. Thanks for your comment